# jQuery add data-role="none" to <select> tags

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery mobile and need to add data-role="none" to all of the `<select>` tags on the page

Unfortunately I have no control over how these tags are generated, is there a jQuery command I can use to automatically add this when the page loads?

### UPDATE

After trying everyones suggestions out the data-role="none" attribute does get correctly added but jQuery mobile still processes things.  Is there a way to turn all form handling off by default with jQuery?

Comment: yes, there is. http://api.jquery.com `data-role` is an attribute.

Comment: I updated my answer to incorporate your updated problem, by the way.

Comment: Here's a simple  solution for you, no need for adding additional attributes: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/gAGtS/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an option, in case you have values coming from the server side that you don't want to interfere with, if set:

```
$("select").each(function (i, e) {
    if(typeof $(e).attr("data-role") === "undefined") {
        $(e).data("role", "none");
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Regarding your second problem, you are probably missing this line in your mobileinit event:

```
$.mobile.ignoreContentEnabled = true
```

Comment: All good answers but yours was the only one that reminded me to set ignoreContentEnabled.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

`$('select').attr('data-role', 'none');`

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).bind('pageinit', function() {
    $('select').attr('data-role', 'none');
});
```

or

```
$(document).bind('pageinit', function() {
    $('select').data('role', 'none');
});
```

last one does'nt change the attribute, but stores the value in jQuery's data().

Answer (score 2):

So when page loads and add data-role="none" to select tags,  you can add this script :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('select').data('role','none');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

After page load use jQuery.attr.

```
$(function(){
   $('select').attr('role-data', 'none');
});
```